# Ask a user for integers until they enter control+a. Then sum up the integers and display the total

Tags: bash

I've been working on some bash scripts and kind of hit a wall.
I need to ask a user to enter a bunch of different integers, and when they press 'control+a'
it'll sum up every integer they entered, like this:

```
10                                                                     
10                 
2           
"control+a"          
22
```

I'm not sure where to even start on this.
I really appreciate the help, thank you.

Comment: it's a bit tricky to deal with `<c-a>`. could you use, for example, a dot (`.`) to mark the end?

Comment: Or just an empty line.

Comment: please show what you've tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your terminal supports it:

```
#!/bin/bash

stty eof ^A

back2default(){ stty eof ^D; }
trap back2default EXIT

declare -i sum=0
while true; do
  read -r foo
  [[ -z $foo ]] && break
  sum+=$foo
done

echo "sum: $sum"
```